# jQuery image uploading, how do I validate image dimensions before upload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

before uploading, how do I validate **width and height** with jQuery

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the question or rather where is it ?

Comment: Checking the Height and width of any image uploaded on client side is not possible. There may be some jQuery plugins, try googling them, but this plugins will be very heavy in size. to avoid page size issue you will have to validate the image height and width on server side. if you suggest u will get the code.

Comment: can u explain in simple english what you need???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery uploadify plugin .

Here is the sample code I have for asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
   var id = "55";
   var theString = "asdf";
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fileInput').uploadify({
   'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
   'script': 'Upload.ashx',
   'scriptData': { 'id': id, 'foo': theString},
   'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
   'auto': true,
   'multi': true,
   'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
   'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
   'queueSizeLimit': 90,
   'sizeLimit': 4000000,
   'buttonText': 'Choose Images',
   'folder': '/uploads',
   'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

   }
 });
```

});

Then you want to make a Handler (.ashx):

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file= context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

            int id = (Int32.Parse(context.Request["id"]));
            string foo = context.Request["foo"];
            file.SaveAs("C:\\" + id.ToString() + foo + file.FileName);

            context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

validating width and height of to-be-uploaded image is not possible on the client-side.

however after upload you can get the width and height of the image in this:

```
var height = $("#Image").height()
var width = $("#Image").width()
```

Comment: FileUpload control is handled with asp.net not jquery.

Comment: Furthermore you could use the javascript `Image()` object - http://www.proglogic.com/learn/javascript/lesson10.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
private void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  {

    //Determine type and filename of uploaded image
    string UploadedImageType = UploadedPicture.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString().ToLower();
    string UploadedImageFileName = UploadedPicture.PostedFile.FileName;

    //Create an image object from the uploaded file
    System.Drawing.Image UploadedImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(UploadedPicture.PostedFile.InputStream);

    //Determine width and height of uploaded image
    float UploadedImageWidth = UploadedImage.PhysicalDimension.Width;
    float UploadedImageHeight = UploadedImage.PhysicalDimension.Height;

    //Check that image does not exceed maximum dimension settings
    if (UploadedImageWidth > 600 || UploadedImageHeight > 400) {
            Response.Write("This image is too big - please resize it!");
    }
```

}

(Or) you can try with this [uploader](http://www.plupload.com/) where you can determine common width and height before user uploads which will work in Chrome,Firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

server Side (C#);

```
using (System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUploadJcrop.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    if (myImage.Width > 500)
    {
        Double d = (myImage.Height * 500) / myImage.Width;
        Int32 myH = (Int32)Math.Round(d, 0);
        Bitmap src = Bitmap.FromStream(FileUploadJcrop.PostedFile.InputStream) as Bitmap;
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(500, myH);
        using (Graphics myg = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)result))
        {
            myg.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, 500, myH);
        }
        result.Save(savePath);
        FileSaved = true;
    }
}
```